# Error: Could not find or load main class OSNameGenerator

Tags: java, batch-file

I created a simple java class which gets the name of the operating system. I also created a batch file to run the java class with the bundled JAVA 7. It seemed to work fine in my system. But when I copied this file and ran the script in another system it threw **Error: Could not find or load main class OSNameGenerator** .

At first I thought This may have to do something with the script and that it is not able to find the bundled java due to some issues in path. But even simply running java file only from the cmd also is not working.

I know this feels is so simple yet I'm not able to find what is creating the issue here.

Here is my java class

```
    public class OSNameGenerator{



    public static void main(String[] args){

        System.out.println(System.getProperty("os.name"));
    }


}
```

and This my batch script

```
"%~dp0\jre\bin\java.exe"  OSNameGenerator

 pause
```

And this is my file structure

[image]

Please help me to find out what is wrong with this.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an issue with classpath.

I fixed it by changing the classopath to current directory using (.) operator in my scrpit.

Here is my updated script

```
.\jre\bin\java.exe -cp . OSNameGenerator

pause
```